# Port conflict while running Integrated weblogic Server in JDeveloper

Tags: jdeveloper

The message i see when i try to run Integrated Weblogic server is 
    Port conflicts have been detected and the affected ports have been automatically reassigned to available ports.

Then I am unable to start my server. I have tried restarting the server but it did not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Windows**

Press `Ctrl+Shft+Esc` click on `Processes`, End the `JDeveloper(jDev64W.exe in my case)` and `Java instances(java.exe in my case)`. Now restart the JDeveloper and try running the Integrated Weblogic Server again.

**Linux**

Use the command `jps -l`. Select the process id corresponding to weblogic.server.
Use `kill -9 <process-id>` to kill the running instance

If it still does not work, restart the computer to ensure all the ports have been released.